# Can I use "propOrder" on <List> items in JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb, marshalling

Working on a XML-parsing solution and I've hit a dead end. Would be grateful if someone knew what to do here. I've tried to unlist the items and added them separately but that didn't quite work since the marshalling just printed out the last element with the same XmlType(name="process") annotation.

This is the problem:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlType(propOrder = {"simple","processList","logList","logList","processList","to","logList","aggregate"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class When {

    @XmlElement
    private String simple ="${body} != null";

    @XmlElement(name="process")
    private List<Process> processList = new ArrayList<Process>();

    public void setProcessList(List<Process> processList) {
        this.processList = processList;
    }


    @XmlElement(name="log")
    private List<Log> logList = new ArrayList<Log>();

    public void setLogList(List<Log> logList) {
        this.logList = logList;
    }

    @XmlElement
    private To to;

    @XmlElement
    private Aggregate aggregate;

    public void setAggregate(Aggregate aggregate) {
        this.aggregate = aggregate;
    }

    public void setTo(To to) {
        this.to = to;
    }
}
```

As you can see I've used lists to add different "process" items to the XML. But I can't order the items. They print like this when I marshal them.

```
<when>
    <simple>${body} != null</simple>
    <process ref="identifyFileTypeFromRouteProcessor"/>
    <process ref="archiveFileProcessor"/>
    <log message="File ${file:name} fetched"/>
    <log message="Copy files to archive"/>
    <log message="Batching files"/>
    <to uri="#" autoCreate=true"/>
    <aggregate strategyRef="fileAggregator" completionFromBatchConsumer="true">
        <correlationExpression>
            <simple>{headers.fileType}</simple>
        </correlationExpression>
        <to uri="direct:sealFile"/>
    </aggregate>
</when>
```

Tried to just write their names a couple of times in the `propOrder` and see if they would index the values by it self.

I'd like a process first then a log not all processes after each other and all logs after another.

Thank you guys for taking a look at my issue.

Best regards,
Seph

Comment: What (I think) you are trying to do isn't possible. If you need a sequence of elements (say) a, b, a, a, b, b you can't have a list for the a's and another one for the b's. You need a single list into which you have to insert JAXBElement objects that identify the tag to be used and carry the value.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, the problem I might encounter is most likely that the elements in the array will have the same name, I might not be able to change the names of the index values since the list generally link to one "type". But I'm not entirely sure about that. I've approached a new solution that I'm currently working on and that is to have the list values scattered in to single variables and then name them with a number after the element name so for instance: process1, 2, 3 etc and log1, 2, 3 etc. Now it can marshal and print the values but with the numbers after each element.

Comment: After that we created a StringReplace method that will loop through the elements and remove the numbers after it has marshalled before it presents the document.